# Nullable value type comparison with is-operator

Tags: c#, .net

I am wondering, if there is technically any difference between between doing a regular value comparison or doing a value comparison over the `is`-operator in C# when working with a nullable value type.

Given the following example:

```
decimal? value = null;

value < 0; // returns false

value is < 0; // returns false
```

Considering it both returns false, I was just wondering whether there is any technical difference in these 2 comparisons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context the `is` operator is part of pattern matching, meaning it will check the runtime type and then perform that operator `<`. `<` will simply do a value comparison.

For these kind of questions, a good app is sharplab.io which will show a decompiled version of the code, where the the syntactic sugar will be displayed as more plain C# code.

```cs
using System;
public class C {
    public void M() {
        decimal? value = null;
        Console.WriteLine(value < 0); // returns false
        Console.WriteLine(value is < 0); // returns false
    }
}
```

Becomes:

```cs
public class C
{
    public void M()
    {
        Nullable<decimal> num = null;
        Nullable<decimal> num2 = num;
        Console.WriteLine((num2.GetValueOrDefault() < default(decimal)) & num2.HasValue);
        Console.WriteLine(num.HasValue && num.GetValueOrDefault() < 0m);
    }
}
```

https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciDCiDetE+UkALIgLIAUAlJtrjQCYCmAxgJYC2AhgDYD8iAblwCu9RAF5EAO0GdOAbmo0cICAE5SAzsMQAeRAAZysxAHpjyAOwBnRADMul+gsXK1Grc2u6DR0xet3OBycAX1hgoA

Comment: I generally like the content of your answer, but I find your comment _[...] the resulting code is basically the same_ a little bit off. The decompiled version from sharplab.io tells us that (in the case where `value` is `null`) `value < 0` evaluates to `0 < 0 & false` (seeing as the `&` operator evaluates both operands even if the left-hand operand evaluates to `false`), whereas `value is < 0` simply evaluates to `false` (seeing as the `&&` _does not_ evaluate the second operand when the first operand evaluates to `false`). So the `<` comparison is _only conditionally_ done for `value is < 0`.

Comment: @AstridE. i have removed that remark.

Answer (score 1):

The `is` operator is used to check if the run-time type of an object is compatible with the given type or not. So it's kind of type comparison.

Regular value comparison - compares values of objects of the same type.

These are two different meanings and usages.

Comment: Against which type does the is operator check in this case then? Does it check, whether my `value` is of type `int` because 0 is `int` implicitly and therefore return false, or does it actually return false here, because value is in fact not smaller than 0?